# Is it possible to autostart a VMware virtual machine in Windows boot

Tags: windows, boot, virtual-machine, autorun

In Windows; I am using [VMware Workstation 16 Player](https://www.vmware.com/products/workstation-player/workstation-player-evaluation.html) non-commercial version that has anUbuntu Instance.

When Windows booted, I want my Ubuntu Instace to start running automatically as well. Is it possible?

Please note that [wmrun](https://www.vmware.com/pdf/vix160_vmrun_command.pdf) is recommended for this but it does not come along with `VMware Workstation 16 Player` and I don't know where can I downloaded it or is it still supoorted.

Comment: There is a solution, but the VM will only be available after login because it requires a desktop, if you are interested. Alternatively, using Hyper-V is a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WMrun.exe is not available standalone.

VIX API tools support for VMware Player stopped about VIX 1.17.

https://www.vmware.com/support/developer/vix-api/

> The current standalone VIX version 1.17 that you can download from
> Download VMware Workspace ONE doesn't work for VMware Workstation
> Player 15

So to autostart guest machine when Windows starts up, you need to upgrade to VMware Workstation.  I use this here.

If for whatever reason, you do not wish to upgrade to Workstation, then you must forgo the automation and manually start the machines.

Comment: Ah so I need to pay 200$ to able to use this feature

Comment: Yes, you need to acquire a Workstation license.  Otherwise just manually start the machines.

Comment: OK I purchase the upgraded version but unable to make it start on boot, what should I set on the settings?

Comment: There are wmrun commands and parameters in this article:  http://www.vi-toolkit.com/wiki/index.php/Vmrun

Comment: the downloaded file does not contain vmrun.exe :(

Comment: Once you have installed Workstation, vmrun.exe is in Program Files (x86) \ Vmware Workstation. I see it here. VIX documentation and samples are in PF (x86) \ Vmware VIX.

Comment: I only have a folder named VMware Player and VMware VIX both does not have vmrun.exe not sure why

Comment: So then you only upgraded VMware Player.  You do need Workstation for what you want.

Comment: I have installed `VMware Workstation Pro 16`, seems like which also covers VMware Player

Comment: Restart your machine and check the Program Files (X86) as I posted above.  Also check Program Files  [no X86]

Comment: It automatically restarted itself but there is not any folder named `Vmware Workstation` 
:-(

Comment: There must be some issue with your machine. I have had Workstation on this machine here for the 4 years I have had it and for a dozen more years prior to that.

Comment: I verify that `vmrun.exe` showed up after the restart